# Get the process ID of a remote powershell session

Tags: windows, powershell

Remote powershell sessions (PSSessions) have corresponding wsmprovhost processes. How do I get the process ID corresponding to a PSSession? I tried running get-member on a list of powershell sessions and here's a part of what I got:

```
Name                   MemberType
----                   ----------
Equals                 Method
GetHashCode            Method
GetType                Method
ToString               Method
ApplicationPrivateData Property
Availability           Property
ComputerName           Property
ConfigurationName      Property
Id                     Property
InstanceId             Property
Name                   Property
Runspace               Property
IdleTimeout            ScriptProperty
OutputBufferingMode    ScriptProperty
State                  ScriptProperty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$PID` in the script block.

```
PS C:\> $pssession = New-PSSession -ComputerName Demo-1
PS C:\> Invoke-Command -Session $pssession -ScriptBlock { $PID }
1888
PS C:\>
```